# (file) not found in build path

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

I downloaded and decompiled a jar file for a plugin for minecraft, and I added it to eclipse by creating a new java project, Import > archive file > [decompiled jar.zip]

That results in this:

[image: project directories]

After that, I changed a single line of code, then I tryed to export it.

However, when I attempt to export it, I get this message: [image: error]

I have no idea what I'm supposed to do to fix this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

`de` (and not only its content) and the other folders as well must be included in the source folder.

Try to move all the folders (except `META-INF`) and files to `src` and then create your jar.

(Note that there would be a warning if you didn't exclude `META-INF` because it is generated you would override it but it wouldn't prevent generating the jar).

**NOTE**

I don't know what you will do later with this but you'd better use Maven, Gradle (or even Ant) to manage you future jar builds.

Comment: When doing that, all of the imports are not found, and the package name doesn't work :(

Comment: @Peter_Browning My bad! I'm fixing it

Comment: Gradle *must* be used to build Minecraft mods, Eclipse's `Build` feature won't work, due to the obfuscation process. I am unsure about Maven, I don't know if there's a Maven build file that will do the reobf or not.